# How to push notifications with Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement push notification in an Android app.
As I understand, we need a sender and receiver installed on the device.

I googled on GCM an found that I need to create a Project in Google dev console.
I got a project ID and an API key.

I found there are third party applications (mixpanel) which can send
push notifications with the information above.  Can I use Google Play to
send notifications to all app users?

On the programming side, I got permissions required in the `Manifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And a broadcast receiver

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>

        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="com.androidexample.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name="com.androidexample.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
```

From here on, I got confused about the "sender" and "receiver" parts.

Do I have to implement `GCMBroadcastReceiver`?

If I want to implement only the Receiving notification part, how does it look like ?

Any reference to a working code example will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to implement GcmBroadcastReceiver class to catch messages from GCM service. The purpose of the receiver is to start the intent service even if the app is off. Here is the most common implementation:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

The purpose of the intent service is doing something with the caught GCM message:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Getting GCM message fields
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        // Doing something with the message.
        // E.g. showing push notification
    }
}
```

You can see e.g. [this article](http://techlovejump.com/how-to-get-data-from-gcm-google-cloud-messaging-notification-in-android/) for details.